# Reading files with multiple delimiter in column headers and skipping some rows at the end

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter, csv

I am new to `Python` and I would like to use `pandas` for reading the data. I have done some searching and effort to solve my issue but still I am struggling. thanks for your help in advance!

I have a.txt file looking like this;

```
skip1
 A1| A2 |A3 |A4# A5# A6 A7| A8 , A9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

END***
Some other data starts from here
```

The first task is that
I would like to assign A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8 and A9 as column names. However, there are multiple separators such as `' ','|','#'` and this makes hassle to assign separator when reading the file. I tried like this;

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
filelist=glob.glob('*.txt')
print(filelist)

df = pd.read_csv(filelist,skiprows=1,skipfooter=2,skipinitialspace=True, header=0, sep=r'\| |,|#',engine='python')
```

But it seems that nothing is happened when I check Spyder's data explorer df.

The second task is that during the reading removing the data starting with the rows `END***` that I don't need. The header has always the same length. However, skipfooter needs the number of lines to skip, which should be changed between the files.

Some several questions already been asked but It seems I can't make them work on my question!

[how-to-read-txt-file-in-pandas-with-multiple-delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559763/how-to-read-txt-file-in-pandas-with-multiple-delimiters)

[pandas-read-delimited-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103290/pandas-read-delimited-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[import-text-to-pandas-with-multiple-delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551662/import-text-to-pandas-with-multiple-delimiters/26551913)

[pandas-ignore-all-lines-following-a-specific-string-when-reading-a-file-into-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138175/pandas-ignore-all-lines-following-a-specific-string-when-reading-a-file-into-a)

EDIT: about removing the the reading removing the data starting with the rows `END`

If the b.txt file like this
b.txt

```
skip1
 A1| A2 |A3 |A4# A5# A6 A7| A8 , A9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

END123
Some other data starts from here
```

an by using the second solution below;

```
txt = open('b.txt').read().split('\nEND')[0]
_, h, txt = txt.split('\n', 2)
pat = r'[\|, ,#,\,]+'
names = re.split(pat, h.strip())

pd.read_csv(
    pd.io.common.StringIO(txt),
    names=names, header=None,
    engine='python')
```

Getting this,

```
   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Comment: @piRSquared it exactly same as in the example.Just save it as a.txt and read it! That is how I did. Sorry the real file is too big. a.txt is just a representative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the file, then read from string

```
txt = open('test.txt').read().split('\nEND***')[0]
pd.read_csv(
    pd.io.common.StringIO(txt),
    sep=r'\W+',
    skiprows=1, engine='python')

   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

---

We can be very explicit with the parsing of the header and parse the rest of the file as csv

```
txt = open('test.txt').read().split('\nEND***')[0]
_, h, txt = txt.split('\n', 2)
pat = r'[\|, ,#,\,]+'
names = re.split(pat, h.strip())

pd.read_csv(
    pd.io.common.StringIO(txt),
    names=names, header=None,
    engine='python')

   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer but I just found some issues. it seems that A6 and A7 columns are combined. Although they are separated with whitespace and I would prefer to have skip rows starting with `END` because the strings after the `END` changes in other file. I would really appreciate if you could you update your solution based on these issues. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander I changed the `sep`.  It works for this example and should work so long as your column names are contiguous alphanumeric strings.  Your file is of undetermined length.  I won't know how many lines to skip until the end.  According to your file, splitting at `'END'` should work.

Comment: thanks for the updating the `sep` part. Yes my file is of undetermined length. If I change the `END***` to `END**` it does not delete this row and the rest. I guess it is same if there is only `END`. My point is that if there is a rows starting with 'END' remove it and everything after it!

Comment: @Alexander I'm failing to see where this strategy breaks down.  If you have an example where it doesn't work, share it in your post so that I/we can see it.  Then I can address the element that is getting in the way.

Comment: Sorry for misguiding! I edited the OP. Please check the EDIT part. I'll remove it after your comment!

Comment: Ahh, I see.  The `'END***'` is now `'END123'`  Just split on `'END'`

Comment: Spot ON!. Sorry I didn't catch your previous point! Thanks man for your guidance! I really appreciated it!

Comment: No problem, glad we could help.

Comment: I just sent new question about new issue that I encountered and linked to this post! [multiple-delimiters-in-column-headers-also-separates-the-row-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699077/multiple-delimiters-in-column-headers-also-separates-the-row-values)

Answer (score 4):

answering first question:

```
In [182]: df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=r'\s*(?:\||\#|\,)\s*', 
                           skiprows=1, engine='python')

In [183]: df
Out[183]:
   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6 A7  A8  A9
1   2   3   4   5   6      7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6      7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6      7   8   9
```

Comment: apparently, I was confused (-:

Comment: @piRSquared, my answer doesn't answer the second part... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU thanks for the answer for the first part. Is this `\s*` to catch multiple whitespace?

Comment: @Alexander, yes, this RegEx matches any number of consecutive spaces or tabs

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for the info. I Appreciate it!